# Doctrine 2.13.2 Warning: Object of class Enum could not be converted to int

Tags: php, enums, doctrine-orm, php-8.1

Since last week I noticed problem on few places in the app I am working on. After investigation I found that with

```
composer require doctrine/orm 2.13.1
```

Everything is ok, but with:

```
composer require doctrine/orm 2.13.2
```

App brakes on places where I use enum in query like:

```
$builder->...->setParameter('type', Type::VARIANT) // Type is enum
```

I tried to read about it:
[here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2021/03/29/dbal-2.13.html) and [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) but I do not see info about this.
Error is written in title.

Field is mapped via xml with
`name="type" type="smallint" enum-type="Type"`. It is valid, worked for months.

**Does anybody knows why doctrine support for enum does not work, or if not that what could cause this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be related to https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/10066 so i would say downgrade to 2.13.1 and wait for 2.13.4

Comment: Downgraded already. Thanks for info.